# How to prevent a <Clock/> child component to reset its state when parent props changes

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle

I designed a very simple  component that simply displays the current time in the HH:MM format, blinking the semicolon each and every second.

This clock is used by others HOC that could be the direct parent. This very HOC component itself depends on a property that changes each and every minute.

As the HOC property updates, the HOC itself updates, and **therefore makes the clock updates as well**.

This makes the clock reset (I mean the state are reset to their initial values) making the clock renders with a glitch (aka a half-second dash displays, replacing the current time).

How would you prevent my clock to ever reset?

```
function Clock() {
        const separator = '—'
        // = Blinking Time
        const [hour, setHour] = useState('')
        const [sep, _setSep] = useState(separator)
        function setSep(sep) {
            _setSep(sep)
            log(`setSep with "${sep}"`)
        }
        const [min, setMin] = useState('')

        const toggle = useRef(false)


        if (sep === separator) {
            console.warn('*** useState reset!')
        }

        const blinkTime = useCallback(() => {
            toggle.current = !toggle.current
            //console.log('clock toggle is ', toggle.current)
            const now = Math.round(Date.now()*1e-3)
            let time = OlenPEPS.dateTime.time({unixDate: now})
            console.log('clock is: '+time)
            const times = time.split(':')
            setHour(times[0])
            setMin(times[1])
            setSep(toggle.current ? ':' : ' ')
        }, [])

        // == On mount, setup timer callback
        useEffect(() => {
            console.log('mount')

            const timer = setInterval(blinkTime, 0.5e3)
            return () => {
                clearInterval(timer)
                console.log('unmount')
            }
        }, [])

        console.log('render', hour, sep, min)

        return (
        <h1 className="title">
            <strong><span>{hour}</span><div style={{display: 'inline-block', width:'0.5rem', textAlignment: 'center'}}>{sep}</div><span>{min}</span></strong>
        </h1>)
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. When the HOC updates the clock updates too and therefore what? Is the displayed time wrong?

Comment: Say <Clock/> is running for 60 seconds, displaying "10:22", then the HOC updates. Now the clock displays "—" (initial state values) where I'd like it displays "10:23".

Comment: Is there a reason it initialises to "—"? I'm just trying to understand why you can't make it so that the clock just always displays the current time regardless of whether it's the initial render or not

Comment: That's my current quick-and-dirty fix. But I 'd like to know if there is another solution that consists in preventing the child to be forced to initialize itself.